# ¿Me explica alguien como funciona el codigo exactamente?

Tags: java

No lo entiendo del todo este codigo que he creado.

```
package principal;

    public class principal {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Animal p1 = new Animal ("Elefante");
            Animal p2 = p1;

            System.out.println("A1:" + p1.getEspecie());
            System.out.println("A2:" + p2.getEspecie());

            p2.setEspecie("Gato");
            System.out.println("A1:" + p1.getEspecie());
            System.out.println("A2:" + p2.getEspecie());

            p2 = new Animal ("Perro");
            System.out.println("A1:" + p1.getEspecie());
            System.out.println("A2:" + p2.getEspecie());

        }

    }

    package principal;

    public class Animal {

        private String especie;

        public Animal(String especie){
            this.especie = especie;
        }
        public Animal (){

        }
        public Animal(Animal p2){
            especie = p2.especie;
        }
        public String getEspecie(){
            return especie;
        }
        public void setEspecie(String especie){
            this.especie = especie;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si no sabes que mas poner , podrias explicar que es lo que buscas con tu codigo o que es lo que entiendes de momento o cuales son tus dudas

Comment: ¿Cómo creas código que tú mismo no entiendes? Pregunta algo más concreto, ¿exactamente qué parte del código no entiendes? ¿Cuál línea?

Comment: Si no lo entiendes, es porque no lo creaste :)

Answer (score 1):

yo te explico

Tu código imprime esto:

```
A1:Elefante
A2:Elefante
A1:Gato
A2:Gato
A1:Gato
A2:Perro
```

En tu caso, sucede lo siguiente:

p1 es un elefante y p2 es una copia de p1 luego apuntan al mismo objeto. Como ambos estan apuntando al mismo objeto, cambiar cualquiera de ellos cambiara al otro.

imprime

```
A1:Elefante
A2:Elefante
```

Luego p2 modifica su especie y ahora es un gato. Como p1 y p2 apuntan al mismo objeto, al modificar p2 se modifica p1 también.

Imprime

```
A1:Gato
A2:Gato
```

Luego p2 se reinstancia y es una nueva variable, apunta a un objeto nuevo y se le setea perro, luego imprime perro, pero p1 sigue apuntando al otro objeto en memoria luego imprime gato y no se ve modificado

Imprime

```
A1:Gato
A2:Perro
```